# method to process linq group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple list of integers (some values repeated) and process with:

```
var groups = from n in numbers
    group n by n into numGroup
    where numGroup.Count()>1
    select numGroup;
```

I can iterate over the groups with nested loops directly after the linq, but I am having trouble writing a separate method to loop through them. Here is what I have tried.

```
private void PrintGroups(IEnumerable groups, string title)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        txt1.Text += "Group " + ++i + "\r\n"; ;
        foreach (var x in group)
               txt1.Text += "    " + x.ToString() + "\r\n"; ;
     }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like the inner foreach:

"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

But the same code works inline with the linq. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ek0nomik: No, it's only a contextual keyword.

Comment: ouch! Can't believe I didn't spot that. I'm changing it regardless. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like you just need to change the type of your parameter:

```
private void PrintGroups(IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, int>> groups, string title)
```

However, aren't you really just interested in the key and the count? After all, all the values in the group will be the same...

```
private void PrintGroups(IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, int>> groups)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("Group {0}: {1}\r\n", group.Key, group.Count());
    }
    txt1.Text = builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, key and count would be better. Just trying to learn/teach LINQ so slowly realizing things...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Linq one thinks in projections, here is an example where I project the group of numbers into a string which can be displayed to the user.

```
 var nums = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 2 };

 nums.GroupBy (n => n)
     .Select (n => string.Format("Number {0} is found {1} times ({2})", n.Key, n.Count (), string.Join(",", n)))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(strN => Console.WriteLine (strN));

/* Output

Number 1 is found 3 times (1,1,1)
Number 5 is found 2 times (5,5)
Number 6 is found 1 times (6)
Number 2 is found 1 times (2)

*/
```